# apn certificate expired and push notifications not working anymore

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

one of my production apple push notifications expired and my push notifications service stopped working.

I thought that I could just renew it and they will start working again.

The thing is that one more developer works on the same apple developer account and he deleted in the meantime all the expired certificates.

So, I created a new one and I updated the keys on my server. But the push notifications are not working..
I'm using their feedback service but I do not get any error back. It says that notification transmitted to the device token I'm targeting.

What can be wrong?
Can the live app get push notifications again without updating it with a new certificate ?

And is it ok if I use an apn certificate on the server that was generated with a different Certificate Signing Request than the certificate that the app was signed with ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that renewing the APNS certificates on live apps works fine. I've used the process you describe above.

One (obvious) point is to make sure you're using the appropriate sandbox versus production cert.

A mistake I've made is to install the app on my phone as a sandbox version and then failed to receive production APNS messages.

Comment: but what if i create a new push certf instead of renewing the older one.. with a new key value pair in the certf now, old version of my app won't receive the push right?

Comment: sorry - haven't had experience of that